# Usb HDD stops working with Task being blocked

Tags: arch-linux, usb-storage, raspberry-pi

I started using a Raspberry Pi with an up to date Arch Linux Images.

The configuration is a simple raspberry pi Ver. B, bought about 2 weeks ago ( so the usb limitation is fixed ), a 8GB SD Card for the main system, an external powered USB Hub and a 1TB Toshiba e.store basic usb hdd.

The System is fully installed and works. The only problem is my HDD. From time to time the HDD stops working out of a sudden. 
At the begging I thought it's might a faulty file system, so I reformatted it to ext3 (GUID Partition Table). Then I thought it's a problem or something with setting the hdd to sleep mode cause hdparm was giving me this weird error.

```
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  f0 00 01 00 50 40 ff 0a 00 00 00 00 00 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

So I wrote a cronjob which uses 'touch' to perform some action on the hard drive every minute, but the behavior still occured.

From time to time the hdd just stopped working, the power led went black and when I tried to do something on the hdd my ssh connection just hang and no interrupt signal or something did work.

This is what dmesg says to my error:

```
[35282.602948] INFO: task scsi_eh_0:52 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[35282.626554] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[35282.652268] scsi_eh_0       D c055dd0c     0    52      2 0x00000000
[35282.652368] [<c055dd0c>] (__schedule+0x2ec/0x638) from [<c055caa4>] (schedule_timeout+0x16c/0x248)
[35282.652424] [<c055caa4>] (schedule_timeout+0x16c/0x248) from [<c055e254>] (wait_for_common+0x108/0x190)
[35282.652472] [<c055e254>] (wait_for_common+0x108/0x190) from [<c03fe810>] (command_abort+0xa4/0xec)
[35282.652538] [<c03fe810>] (command_abort+0xa4/0xec) from [<c03af1a4>] (scsi_error_handler+0x378/0x484)
[35282.652576] [<c03af1a4>] (scsi_error_handler+0x378/0x484) from [<c00422c0>] (kthread+0x84/0x90)
[35282.652616] [<c00422c0>] (kthread+0x84/0x90) from [<c000eac0>] (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
```

Any idea's why this happens all the time?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Like I mentioned, the USB HDD is connected through the usb hub which is powered externally. The cable is definitely not bad as it's a brand new hdd and the hdd just works fine on my mac ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while of investigation I found several similar bugs in connection with an old bug in the 3.6 Linux Kernel which is the default Kernel on the Arch/Raspberry Pi Installation guide.

I finally managed to update my pi then to the latest kernel builds using

```
pacman -Sy linux-raspberrypi-latest linux-headers-raspberrypi-latest
```

which installs the newest Kernel builds for you. (Currently something around 3.9.x)

No more problems since then ;)